# tar unpack : Unexpected EOF in archive

Tags: 10.10, eclipse, tar, gzip

I have downloaded `eclipse-platform-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`.

Using Ubuntu 10.10  64-bit on Intel 64-bit processor.

While trying to unpack the contents (either double-click or right-click & open-with-archive-manager) I get this error:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file<br/>
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive<br/> 
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there any remedy to repair it? or is the downloaded file corrupt & needs to be re-downloaded?

Comment: I renamed the file from ".tar.gz" to just ".tar"     Then fired command "tar xzvf eclipse-platform-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar    It did some unpacking.  Then at a certain point, the same error is thrown as I wrote in my question.

Comment: There are two ways to go troubleshooting. Knock out the easy one first: `md5sum eclipse-platform-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` which should match exactly with the Md5 sum published for that file, which I think may be here, but not sure: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/checksum/eclipse-platform-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz.md5

Comment: Thanks Chris for your input. In the meantime, I booted to Win7 and extracted the contents through WinRar. It extracted....

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of you haven't gotten the entire archive downloaded. Try to download it again and have another go at it.

I just had a go with it. Downloaded the file from the eclipse site. The link I got was `http://eclipse.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/eclipse//eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/eclipse-platform-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`. This file checks out ok on md5sum and extracts without any problems.

Comment: I re-download the same.  But no success.  Same error.

Comment: Had to try for myself. No problems here. Updated my answer with the download link I got from eclipse web.

Comment: In the meantime, I booted to Win7 and extracted the contents through WinRar. It extracted.... Now further problem is-- I added a line in "eclipse.ini" as -- "...-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni after -vmargs. But it does not open Eclipse. It says "Could not display "/tmp/eclipse/eclipse"." There is no application installed for executable files”. What do I need to do for this?

Comment: I sorry to say that I know nothing of eclipse and how it works.